# Can I fetch the data being given to an app by its host and store it locally?

Tags: android

I would like to preface my query by saying that I am an absolute beginner when it comes to programming but I really want to realise this project so every little help is deeply appreciated.

I am trying to build an app that needs accurate train data for it to work and from my current research as there is not central government API for railway data , the only accurate data source for train location that I can find is in an other app that uses crowd sourcing to pinpoint the location.

I wanted to know if it is possible to fetch that train data from that app and then use it on my own as it would make my app a lot more reliable and accurate.

The issue currently is that the app only shows graphical representation of the data thats being fed to it from its servers , so I wanted to know if there is a way to access the actual data being sent to the app.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let me clarify, this is a very broad question and hence will have a very broad answer too.

As far as I can understand from your question is that you want to show **TRUE** location on a map.

For this, you will have to understand the complete Tracking scenario. Let me explain it to you step-wise below:

1. There is an app, installed on a device (user) which fetches the GPS location (**REAL**) data and keeps sending it to a server (backend).
2. This GPS data is the Lattitude-Longitude coordinates of the device (user).
3. The server stores this information in their database for queries.
4. There is another user, different than the one currently sending the location data, who wants to know the location of the first user. The app which he is using will request the server (backend) to send the location data for the device. Which, in turn, will send the latest location data (LatLng coordinates) to the current app. This app will then show the location data over a map.

Now, usually, this process is followed to show one-to-one location data. However, in scenarios like Train Location etc, servers usually collect **pool** of location data, being received from several users, to cross-verify the actual location (average out, mean, location optimization algorithms etc.) and then display that information over a map.

As per your requirement, which I can understand, you want to get this **REAL** data directly from either another app or from the server. If you want to get the location data from the server, you will need an API, which serves as a Request-Response platform. However, if you are looking to get the data from another app, it would rather be simpler to get the location data directly, as your APP will also be installed on the device itself.

I would suggest you to kindly read about getting and processing location data, communication with servers over API etc for better understanding and implementation of your requirements.

Comment: Wow, first of all thanks a lot for your REALLY well written answer,and that too in such a short time as well. 

I will now try to learn more about location data and how to communicate with another app, since I am not entirely sure if it is possible to access the data being sent to another app.

I will try to educate myself a bit more so I can ask a better question next time.
Thank you for you assistance, Cheers ^-^

Comment: @udbhavshrivastava Glad, it helped. If you ever need help, feel free to contact me again.